# skip common "data" and extract its list content directly on marshalling

Tags: jax-rs, jsonb, microprofile

I request a list of users and wanted to do it like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
List<User> users();
```

However, the json-response consumed looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"user":"test1"},{"user":"test2"}]}
```

The list of interest is wrapped within the json `data`-field. Because of that, I have to use a wrapper class like this:

```
public final class ResponseWrapper<T> {

    @JsonbProperty("data")
    private final List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and use this in my restclient-interface:

```
@GET
@Path("/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
ResponseWrapper<User> users();
```

To get the list of interest I need to call `client.users().data()`.

Is there a trick or a configuration in `microprofile restclient` or `jsonb` or `jax-rs` to skip this `data`-field directly and only use/extract the list or do I have to use such solution above by introducing another wrapper class?